# Listbox that shows Picture from its directory

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a program that shows a folders directory in a list box. So every file in the C:\Pics folder/directory appears in the list box, at the moment this works correctly. So far I have also figured out how to only show .JPG files in the folder C:\Pics. Now I am also trying to figure out how I can then view these pictures using some sort of OnClick in the list box, which the picture will then be shown in a picture box on the form.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Here is my code so far....

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Pics"))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Pics");


                FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.JPG");
                foreach (FileInfo f in fi)
                {


                    lstpic.Items.Add(f.Name);

                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("The Directory does not exist");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the list box click event to your `Form1` code. Let's say you use the picture box to diplay pictures:

```
private void lstpic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Pics\" + (string)lstpic.SelectedItem;
}
```

You can obviously do what you want, `(string)lstpic.SelectedItem` will contain the name of the file you stored in the list box.

Comment: When I click on the picture in the listbox it shows a red cross in the picturebox why is this?

Comment: It suggests it cant find the filepath

Comment: Yes, you need a path or otherwise you're reading from the folder where  your assembly is executed.

Comment: See my edit but it would be better if you created a variable, constant or property on your form class to store the path.

Comment: Is there anyway I can set the pictures to be a certain height and width?

Comment: You can change the width and height of the picture box. But this is really a separate question. Please ask a new question with the new code you have.